# Multiple lines of text not accessible in $select/$expand query : Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

On-site enterprise install of SP 2013.

I have a list called Questions.  This list has a Title, ID, and a custom field called "Question" that is a Multiple Line of Text field set to type: Plain Text.

I've created a second list called LPA_Questions that contains a Lookup to my Questions list.  So far so good.  Although I should note that I notice when setting up this custom column, the Question column is not one of my choices to display - I'm only offered Id, Title, Modified, Created Version.

So, I'm trying to execute a _api/web query on the LPA_Questions list and expand the Question field.

This works:

```
    _api/web/lists/getbytitle('LPA_Questions')/items?$filter=&$top=0&$select=Id,Question/Id&$expand=Question
```

This does not:

```
 _api/web/lists/getbytitle('LPA_Questions')/items?$filter=&$top=0&$select=Id,Question/Id,Question/Question&$expand=Question
```

Error:

> The query to field 'Question/Question' is not valid.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Just for fun I tried this:

_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LPA_Questions?$select=Question/Id,Question/Title,Question/Question&$expand=Question

The listdata.svc had no problems.  Is there a difference in the way the _api/web handles things and listdata.svc?

Comment: I too am having this issue. Did you ever fix it?

Comment: http://dinushaonline.blogspot.in/2014/09/get-multiple-lines-of-text-field-value.html

Comment: The problem is that `$expand` only supports a limited set of column types.  [This other answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/203358/92071) says that you can only `select/expand` columns that are single line of text, date/time, or number. I don't have a good way to work around this, other than to select the linked `Question` by ID using a second call.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the query string (my caps may be off) `&$select=FieldValuesAsText,FieldValuesAsHtml&$expand=FieldValuesAsText,FieldValuesAsHtml`

This should allow for those fields to be returned inside of the FieldValuesAsText key/node

Comment: Nope. Your example isn't referencing a lookup field.

_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Project_Team')/items?$select=Project/Description&$expand=Project

This example expands Project (the lookup field) and tries to retrieve the Project/Description field which is a Rich Text field. Sharepoint responds with "The query to field 'Project/Description' is not valid."

Comment: I tried as you said, however, expading the select items query to also FieldValuesAsHtml etc... only returns the URI for that column, not the rest of the data :(