# Querying multiple lines of text column via REST API

Tags: rest, ms-office

I am trying to query a simple multiple lines of text column on a custom list in SharePoint 2013 on-prem. Whenever I include the text column in the $select fields I get an error that the field is not valid.

I found another person who is having the same issue but there were no replies to their post. [Multiple lines of text not accessible in $select/$expand query : Sharepoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/111895/multiple-lines-of-text-not-accessible-in-select-expand-query-sharepoint-2013)

I would rather not have to use listdata.svc and would rather not have to make another round trip just for one field. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**
The error is the same as the other post.

> The query to field '[MyList]/[MyField]' is not valid.

Here is the REST query. The reason I am using $expand is because I am querying off a lookup field on MyParentList that points to MyChildList.

This generates the error above:

> /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[MyParentList]')/items(1)?$select=Id,Title,Introduction,[LookupField]/Id,[LookupField]/[MultilineTextField]&$expand=[LookupField]

This does not:

> /_api/web/lists/getByTitle('[MyParentList]')/items(1)?$select=Id,Title,Introduction,[LookupField]/Id&$expand=[LookupField]

I am actually querying a bunch of other fields, all single line of text, and they work fine. I truncated the queries for readability. I can guarantee you with 100% certainty I am not using an invalid field name.

Comment: What field are you trying to get the text from? Is it an OOTB field or custom?

Comment: Post the error message.

Comment: Its a custom field defined in a list instance schema.xml that is deployed via a sandboxed WSP. It's pretty simple.

Comment: I haven't had any problems querying a multiple line of text field before.  You shouldn't need to expand on it like the other post says.  I was asking what kind of field it was to figure out if you are using the correct internal column name.  Can you verify that?

Comment: Can you post your REST query?  As @Jordan mentioned, `$expand` is not necessary for multi lines of text.

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Is the multi-line field plain text or rich text?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same behavior in SharePoint Online right now, so it appears that it is what it is. I can expand and select a single line text field, but I get a 400 Bad Request when I try to select a multi line text field, with the same message you're getting:

> "The query to field 'LU/Multi' is not valid."

Comment: I edited my response, because my first response was just wrong ;)