# Identify "additional" Lookup field and select its value via OData select/expand

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column

I've created a list "My List" with a column called "RelatedRecord", which is a lookup against other items in "My List".  When I defined the column, I selected the field "Title" under `In this column:`, and also selected "ID" under `Add a column to show each of these additional fields:`.  When I look at the list in Sharepoint, I see a "Related Record" column with a link to the other item, and I see a column "RelatedRecord:ID" which shows the ID number for the linked item.  This all works as expected.

I am retrieving the items in a web application using the REST API (via the `@pnp/sp` NPM package, but I don't think that's relevant to my question).  I'm trying to dynamically display the list items, so I read the `/lists/getByTitle('My List')/fields` endpoint to determine the structure of the list.  This works well for almost all column types, except this pair of Lookup columns.  The `/fields` endpoint returns (trimmed to what I think is relevant):

```
[{
    "EntityPropertyName": "RelatedRecord",
    "FieldTypeKind": 7,
    "Id": "4550737e-9f64-463f-b948-722b60de461d"
    "InternalName": "RelatedRecord",
    "IsRelationship": true,
    "LookupField": "Title",
    "LookupList": "{5761b1f6-ca0e-4841-81b1-4fff1feee3f0}",
    "LookupWebId": "17d5405b-c55a-4296-ad22-23c59525c414",
    "PrimaryFieldId": null,
    "ReadOnlyField": false,
    "Title": "RelatedRecord",
}, {
    "EntityPropertyName": "RelatedRecord_x003a_ID",
    "FieldTypeKind": 7,
    "Id": "edfc59b3-03b8-4534-820b-cea865b36cbc",
    "InternalName": "RelatedRecord_x003a_ID",
    "IsRelationship": false,
    "LookupField": "ID",
    "LookupList": "{5761b1f6-ca0e-4841-81b1-4fff1feee3f0}",
    "LookupWebId": "17d5405b-c55a-4296-ad22-23c59525c414",
    "PrimaryFieldId": "4550737e-9f64-463f-b948-722b60de461d",
    "ReadOnlyField": true,
    "Title": "RelatedRecord:ID",
}]
```

If I select all items via `/lists/getByTitle('My List')/items`, the result includes a field called `RelatedRecordID`. (Note that neither property has an `EntityPropertyName` with this value!)  I can use `$select`/`$expand` to create a lookup like `/items?$select=*,RelatedRecord/Id,RelatedRecord/Title&$expand=RelatedRecord`.  This returns the values for the two columns that I see when viewing the list in Sharepoint.

I figured this out "manually", but I'd like my application to be able to display arbitrary lists (with lookup columns) by parsing the definitions returned by the `/fields` endpoint. So, my question is, how can I go from the field definitions in the JSON above, to constructing a REST API query for items that adds the correct lookup fields?  The definition for the "additional column" (RelatedRecord:ID) does not actually include the string I need to pass to `$expand` (`RelatedRecord`), or does it give me the information I need to build the correct string to pass to `$select` (`RelatedRecord/ID`).

Comment: Bonus problem: what if the "additional" column is not in [this very short list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203337/rest-api-getting-fields-from-an-lookup-list/203358#203358) of supported column types -- what if, for example, it's "multiple lines of text" or "calculated"? I believe adding an unsupported column as in `$select=RelatedRecord/SomeCalculatedColumn&$expand=RelatedRecord` causes the REST call to fail with an "invalid field" error.

Answer (score 1):

As I was writing this, I found a potential lead: the "additional" column definition (`RelatedRecord:ID`) has a `PrimaryFieldId` property which references the column I actually created (`RelatedRecord`).  Using this, I can build the `$select` argument for the lookup column:

```
const selects = [];
const expands = [];
fieldDefinitions.forEach(field => {
  if (field.PrimaryFieldId) {         // this field is "additional"
    const primary = fieldDefinitions.find(f => f.Id === field.PrimaryFieldId);
    // first part is the name of the "primary column", e.g. "RelatedRecord"
    // second part is the target-list field name, e.g. "ID"
    selects.push(primary.InternalName + "/" + field.LookupField);
  } else {                            // this field is "primary"
    // $select=RelatedRecord/Title&$expand=RelatedRecord
    selects.push(field.InternalName + "/" + field.LookupField);
    expands.push(field.InternalName);
  }
})

query += "$select=" + selects.join(",") + "&$expand=" + expands.join(",");
```

I think this approach will work but I'm still interested in hearing other perspectives, or maybe if there's a better way to do this.  (Please remember, I'm trying to code something that will work against arbitrary lists whose structure I won't know at design-time, so it has to be based on the data returned by `/lists/getByWhatever(...)/fields`.)